# more explication for WriteConsoleOutputAttribute

Tags: c++, winapi

I am working with the Windows console, where I have `while(true)` function with a variable `i +=1;`

I want change the color of my variable so I am using the **[WriteConsoleOutputAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsoleoutputattribute)** function:

```
WriteConsoleOutputAttribute(hConsole, &write, 2, c, &written);
```

My undertanding of the parameters is:

- `hConsole` is the handle of the console *(makes sense)*
- `&write` is the color attribute. For example it can be `FOREGROUND_RED` *(makes sense)*
- `2` is the number of characters *(make sense)*
- `c` is the coordinate X and Y of the console *(makes sense)*

But I'm struggling with the **`&written`** parameter; what does this parameter do?

### Furthermore

I'm having an issue when `i` reaches `10` or more. The first digit (the '1' in the number '10', for instance) appears in red as expected, but the second digit becomes invisible. How can I correct this? Is it related to the `&written` parameter?

Ultimately, my goal is to display the entire value of the variable `i` (whether it's 1, 10, 100, 1000) in red.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsoleoutputattribute): `lpNumberOfAttrsWritten`: A pointer to a variable that receives the number of attributes actually written to the console screen buffer.

Comment: thank you for your fast answer.  A pointer to a variable, but my variable is just an increment number in my variable i +=1, how i cant give it a pointer ? and why when i get the value 10, the zero become invisible

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, because I don't see how the `i` variable is involved in the call to `WriteConsoleOutputAttribute`. Please show more code, create a [mre].

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the second parameter is an array, containing as many elements as specified in the third parameter. In other words, if you have length set to 2, it is not enough to have a single `FOREGROUND_RED` element, you need to provide an array of two `FOREGROUND_RED` elements. See also: [How to use `WriteConsoleOutputAttribute` function correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31587985/1458097).